# Why wont pygame music go backward

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame

I have written very simple code which loads an MP3 and plays the song and I am trying to get the music to go back 5 seconds, but it does not go. It goes 5 seconds on first click, then it goes less than 5 seconds and stop moving forward.

Code:

```
def backwards():
    cur_sec = pygame.mixer.music.get_pos()/1000 - 5
    print(cur_sec) # prints in seconds correctly but never decreases
    pygame.mixer.music.set_pos(cur_sec)
```

Even this relative time gives the same effect as before:

```
import pygame
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load('music.mp3')

Button(root,text='Clikc',command=lambda:pygame.mixer.music.play()).pack()
Button(root,text='Clicker',command=lambda:pygame.mixer.music.set_pos(-5)).pack() #using relative time as said by pygame documentation

root.mainloop()
```

If this is supposed to work perfectly, then I maybe I can give a reproducible example. Is there something about `pygame` I'm forgetting here? Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the document for `get_pos()`:

> This gets the number of milliseconds that the music has been playing
> for. The returned time only represents how long the music has been
> playing; it does not take into account any starting position offsets.

So it may not return the actual position of the music being played.

You need to keep track of the elapsed time yourself and use `rewind()` and `set_pos()` to set the play position of the music.  Below is an example:

```py
import time
import tkinter as tk
import pygame

stime = None

def play():
    global stime
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    stime = time.time()

def backwards():
    global stime
    if stime:
        elapsed = time.time() - stime
        delta = min(elapsed, 5)
        pygame.mixer.music.rewind()
        pygame.mixer.music.set_pos(elapsed-delta)
        stime += delta # adjust the "play start time" after backwards

root = tk.Tk()

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("Leader of the Band.mp3")

tk.Button(root, text="Play", width=10, command=play).pack()
tk.Button(root, text="Back 5s", width=10, command=backwards).pack()

label = tk.Label(root, font="Consolas 12")
label.pack()

# function to show the music elapsed time
def tick():
    global stime
    if not pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
        stime = None
    elapsed = time.time()-stime if stime else 0
    mins, secs = divmod(elapsed, 60)
    label.config(text=f"{mins:02.0f}:{secs:06.3f}")
    label.after(100, tick)

tick()

root.mainloop()
```

---

Update: adding "pause" feature:

```py
import time
import tkinter as tk
import pygame

stime = None
is_paused = False
elapsed = 0

def play():
    global stime, is_paused
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
    stime = time.time()
    is_paused = False
    pause_btn.config(text="Pause")

def backwards():
    global stime, is_paused, elapsed
    if stime and not is_paused:
        elapsed = time.time() - stime
        delta = min(elapsed, 5)
        '''
        pygame.mixer.music.rewind()
        pygame.mixer.music.set_pos(elapsed-delta)
        '''
        pygame.mixer.music.play(start=elapsed-delta)
        stime += delta

def pause():
    global is_paused, stime, elapsed
    is_paused = not is_paused
    now = time.time()
    if is_paused:
        elapsed = now - stime  # save the elapsed time
        pygame.mixer.music.pause()
        pause_btn.config(text="Resume")
    else:
        pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
        pause_btn.config(text="Pause")
        stime = now - elapsed # adjust the start time

root = tk.Tk()

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("Leader of the Band.mp3")

tk.Button(root, text="Play", width=10, command=play).pack()
back_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Back 5s", width=10, command=backwards)
back_btn.pack()
pause_btn = tk.Button(root, text="Pause", width=10, command=pause)
pause_btn.pack()

label = tk.Label(root, font="Consolas 12")
label.pack()

def tick():
    global stime, elapsed
    if not is_paused:
        if not pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
            stime = None
        elapsed = time.time()-stime if stime else 0
        mins, secs = divmod(elapsed, 60)
        label.config(text=f"{mins:02.0f}:{secs:06.3f}")
    back_btn.config(state="disabled" if is_paused else "normal")
    label.after(100, tick)

tick()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I was trying to figure out on adding a pause button, but since `pygame.mixer.music.get_busy()` will return `False` when paused, `stime` becomes `None`? Any ideas on adding a pause button?

Comment: Adding pause function will make the logic of tracking the elapsed time a bit complicate.

Comment: Hmmm I agree, anyway thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you mind when the music is paused, the `back 5s` function is disabled?  If yes, I can update my solution.